# Combining SQL select statements

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 select statements I want to combine them in one:

```
SELECT pp_from 
FROM relations 
WHERE type = 2 
  AND id_to = $g_RequesterId 
ORDER BY rank_from DESC

SELECT pp_to 
FROM relations 
WHERE type = 2 
  AND id_from = $g_RequesterId 
ORDER BY rank_to DESC
```

Is it possible that the returning result is sorted correctly where `rank_from` and `rank_to` are both integer?

Comment: Well you can sort by one and then the other, yes. You'll need to decide what the primary order should be

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) - including, always provide sample source data, and expected result. Then there is no danger of ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Try to join it with ROW_NUMBERs. Like that:

```
SELECT 
      t1.pp_from
    , t2.pp_to
FROM 
(
    SELECT pp_from, rank_from, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rank_from DESC) rn 
    FROM relations 
    WHERE type=2 AND id_to=$g_RequesterId 
) t1
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT pp_to, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rank_to DESC) rn 
        FROM relations 
        WHERE type=2 AND id_from=$g_RequesterId 
    ) t2
        ON t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY 
    t1.rank_from DESC
```